# Exception filter NestJS does not work when delegating

Tags: exception, filter, websocket, nestjs, nestjs-exception-filters

I am using a gateway to emit events.

For clarity reasons, I created files that make the link between services and this gateway.

For example, in gateway :

```
    @SubscribeMessage('createRoom')
    async createRoom(client: Socket, channel: newChannelDto) {
        this.chatService.createRoom(client, channel)
    }
```

In Chat service :

```
    async createRoom(client: Socket, channel: newChannelDto)
    {
        await this.channelService.createChannel(channel.chanName, client.data.user, channel.password, channel.private)
        client.join(channel.chanName)
        for (let [allUsers, socket] of this.gateway.activeUsers.entries())
            this.gateway._server.to(socket.id).emit('rooms', " get rooms ", await this.channelService.getChannelsForUser(allUsers));
    }
```

where :

- gateway is the injected gateway, and _server, declared as

```
@WebSocketServer()
    public _server : Server
```

the server contained in Gateway.

I made a WS/HTTP/Query failed exception filter, included on top of my Gateway via @UseFilters(new MyCustomExceptionsFilter()).

Before I move functions to the "children" files, my filter was able to catch everything, but since I moved them away from gateway, it does not work anymore ; I am still able to catch them manually, but they are not sent to front anymore.

Example of output in my terminal, that I was once able to catch/send as user-friendly error:

```
api         | Error: this is still thrown if caught manually
api         |     at /api/src/websocket/chat.service.ts:67:28
api         |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
api         |     at ChatService.createRoom (/api/src/websocket/chat.service.ts:66:3)
```

Comment: Why are you not `await`ing the `this.chatService.createRoom(client, channel)` call?

Comment: Approximately spent 4 hours turning around all possible solutions and not even thinking about this one - thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the `await` in the gateway call, the promise is not properly handled the the lifecycle of the request, as Nest sees it, ends, so when an error happens it is outside of the exception zone that Nest is responsible for. Add `await` to the `this.chatService.createRoom(client, channel)` and all should be good from there

Comment: That was exactly the problem and totally make sense now ; however, I still hav a question ; how is Nest still able to catch it manually with for example ```this.chatService.createRoom(client, channel).catch((err) => {console.log(err)})``` ? Why is it here "waiting" the request ? I usually spot await errors when getting 'undefined' instead of expected object, but here, error was still well caught at the end

Comment: Are you wondering why you still got responses on your client side? That's due to the `this.gateway._server.to()` call you have. It's similar to a `res.send()`, but doesn't cause an issue as you can send multiple responses with sockets. In Nest's eyes, because the promise is not awaited, the async method resolves immediately, but you can still have code run in the background, Nest just won't handle it